# Appropriate way to return an arrayref from a sub with optional sorting in Perl version 5.20

Tags: sorting, perl, subroutine, arrayref

I try to write a subroutine under Perl 5 version 5.20, that creates a large directory list stored in an array. The subroutine returns the result as an arrayref. For convenience reasons I want the have the option to sort the result.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.20;
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp qw(read_dir);
use Time::HiRes;

use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings 'once';
no warnings 'experimental';
no warnings 'experimental::signatures';

my $PATH='/net/dbfs/GRM-RS/Flight-Campaigns/2021-08-23.Ram-Head-i-22.SE-01/cam/MM010259/iiq/';


sub fsReadDir($base, $sort, $mode = 1) {
    $base    //= '.';         # Base path default is the current path
    $sort    //= 0;           # Flag for array sorting of the result 
    my @res=read_dir($base);
    if ($sort) {
       return [sort(@res)] if $mode == 1;
       if ($mode == 2)  {
           @res = sort(@res);
           return \@res;
       }
    } else {  
        return \@res;
    } 
}

sub testSorting($sort, $mode, $max = 1000) {
    my $start = [Time::HiRes::gettimeofday()];   
    my $count = 0;
    for my $ix (0..$max) {
        my $array = fsReadDir($PATH, $sort, $mode );
        $count = @$array;
    }
    my $end   = time();
    my $dif = Time::HiRes::tv_interval($start);
    print "SORT: $sort MODE: $mode COUNT: $count TIME: $dif s\n"
}

testSorting(0, 1);
testSorting(1, 1);
testSorting(1, 2);
```

### Results

```
/usr/bin/env perl "test-array.pl"
SORT: 0 MODE: 1 COUNT: 14861 TIME: 6.882694 s
SORT: 1 MODE: 1 COUNT: 14861 TIME: 9.131504 s
SORT: 1 MODE: 2 COUNT: 14861 TIME: 8.622628 s
```

What is the effective way to sort the array directly at the `return` level?

Comment: How does that fail?

Comment: Tip: There's a missing `my` on vars for args. ALWAYS use `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Tip: The prototype for `fsReadDir` is incorrect. You indicate the sub takes zero arguments, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: Tip: Avoid the needless capture in default value for `$exclude`

Comment: Tip: `@res = sort(@res) if $sort;` might be slightly faster since that's optimized into an in-place sort.

Comment: The options for different values of `$mode` do the same ?

Comment: @zdim Hopefully gort right now.

Comment: For both values of `$mode` (`1` or `2`) it sorts, in the same way, and returns an arrayref of the sorted `@res`. So the value of `$mode` doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Altogether, why not sort out all sorting, obtain the final `@res`, and return its ref.  It's simpler and clearer.  If you return conditionally, also while doing some processin in that statement, things can get complicated.  (You can do `return $sort ? [ sort @res ] : \@res;` but as soon as processing gets more complex that may get unwieldy.  Also, as ikegami said, sorting-in-place (`@res = sort @res if $sort;`) may make it a little faster.

Comment: @zdim I'm looking for the appropriate way to do this in common. The conditionals are for tests only. I extracted from your comments, that `return $sort ? [ sort @res ] : \@res;` is the best way to do this. Can you provide an answer, I will vote and close the question then.

Comment: It seems to me your timings will be heavily influenced by the big directory read I/O.  If you're really interested in `sort` time efficiency _per se_, perhaps just [Benchmark](https://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark) the different sorting approaches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you insist on sorting out the sorting business in the `return` statement itself can use a ternary

```
return $sort ? [ sort @res ] : \@res;
```

This may be all well and clear enough in simple cases.

However, I find it clearer to first deal with cases and options and then return the result

```
@res = sort @res if $sort;

if    ($mode == 1) { ... }   # modes given in the question do nearly the same,
elsif ($mode == 2) { ... }   # but imagine different processing based on value
...

return \@res;
```

Also, sorting in place should be a little more efficient.

If this were about efficiency then you'd want to benchmark different approaches, and under realistic circumstances.  For one, it may all get blown out of the water by reading a large directory, when one may not be able to tell any performance difference in how exactly the return is constructed.

So I'd go for clarity, until it is clearly seen that the choice does affect performance.